# Codeigniter 2.1 - load data into view on view in foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have this template file:

```
<article class="box vest p10">
    <h2 class="box_naslov"><?php echo $vst['naslov'] ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo word_limiter($vst['opis'], 25) ?></p>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/vesti/update/' . $vst['id_clanak']) ?>">Izmeni Vest</a>
    <a role=obrisi href="<?php echo base_url('admin/vesti_delete/' . $vst['id_clanak']) ?>">Obriši Vest</a>

    <?php
        $slider = $vst['slider'] == 0 ? 'Ubaci u slider'  : 'Izbaci iz slider-a';
        $q = $vst['slider'] == 0 ? 'ubaci'  : 'izbaci';
     ?>
    <a role=slider  href="<?php echo base_url('admin/vesti_slider/' . $vst['id_clanak'] . '?q=' . $q )?>"><?php echo $slider ?></a>
</article>
```

In my view file I have tried this:

```
<?php foreach ($vesti_slider as $vst): ?>
    <?php $this->load->view('templates/admin/vesti', $vst) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I got error - ** Undefined variable: vst**. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: I dont see $vesti_slider anywhere.....are you sure you dont mean to do foreach($vst['slider'] as $vst)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass data to a view as an array (or object), with the key becoming the variable name.

```
<?php foreach ($vesti_slider as $vst): ?>
    <?php $this->load->view('templates/admin/vesti', array('vst' => $vst)) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```